# Picking a random value from a list of values of a self declared datatype

Tags: haskell, random

What I'm trying to is write a function that picks a random card out of all the possible cards that can be picked. The cards are of a type I declared named rank. My code looks like this:

```
data Rank = Ace | Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten
            | Jack | Queen | King
            deriving(Eq, Ord, Bounded, Enum, Show, Read)

pickCard :: Rank
pickCard = error "How should I pick a random card here? :("
```

Of course what I want this function to be doing is to pick a random value from list `[Ace .. King]` How can I do this? Please bear in mind that I'm a beginner at Haskell and Functional programming in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Haskell functions are referentially transparent, this means that if you put the same thing into a function, you get the same thing out. So there's no function like

```
random :: () -> Int
```

That returns different results every time you use it. There are a few ways to approach this, the simplest is to use the existing facilities for randomness.

```
import System.Random -- requires the random package from Hackage

instance Random Rank where -- Describes how to choose random card
  randomR (a,b) = over toEnum . randomR (fromEnum a, fromEnum b)
    where over f (a, b) = (f a, b)
  random = randomR (minBound, maxBound)

pickCard :: IO Rank
pickCard = randomIO

-- Or we can pass in a source of randomness and pass out the new one
pickCard :: RandomGen g => g -> (Rank, g)
pickCard = random
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I get an error though: Couldn't match type `g0 -> (Int, g0)' with `Int'
    Expected type: (Int, Int) -> Int
      Actual type: (Int, Int) -> g0 -> (Int, g0)
    In the second argument of `(.)', namely `randomR'
    In the expression: toEnum . randomR
    In the expression: toEnum . randomR $ (fromEnum a, fromEnum b)

Comment: Sorry, but I have one more question. I want use the outcome of the pickCard function as an argument for another. With the IO type this isn't possible..

Comment: No, you have to use something like `fmap someFunction pickCard` which will give you back the result wrapped again in IO, you can't escape the IO monad in Haskell, that's what we mean when we say haskell is pure

Comment: You can avoid living in `IO` as long as you're willing to call `mkStdGen` with some seed value and thread the random state yourself.  Luckily, the [MonadRandom package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.1.12) contains a monadic interface to simplify this very task.  (Of course, purity means you will get the same result on every program run.)